# Is it possible to use avro schema resolution without reader?

Tags: serialization, deserialization, avro

I know there is a way to read avro record into schema compatible with one used to write that record (given both schemas). I wonder whether there is a way to transform record to the similar record with another (but compatible with old one) schema. Compatibility is meant in sense of as it is described [here](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Schema+Resolution).

Comment: Would a serialization roundtrip (writing with the old schema, and reading with the new one) not work for your use-case?

Comment: It would. It is currently actually implemented in this way, but it sounds like smth unnatural. I wonder whether there is a native avro method / constructor to do it in a straight way.

Comment: I'm not aware of any implementation that directly supports this currently (a benefit of this though is that there is a single source of truth for resolution rules). Maybe a contribution opportunity? :)